# fancybox modal property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox-2

I have opened fancybox on page load but whenever i click outside the fancybox it is closed. I want to prevent this and i have already used modal property but it's not working. Here is my code using fancyBox v2.1.4

```
$("#registration").fancybox({
        'width': '40%',
        'height': '40%',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'showCloseButton' : false,
        'modal': true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this function it is fixed..

```
closeClick  : false,
helpers : { 
  overlay : {closeClick: false}
}
```